Proving $f(x-y)+f(\frac{2xy+y^2}{x+y})+f(-\frac{2xy+x^2}{x+y})=2f(\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y})∀(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2 \iff f(x)\in${$ax^2+bx^4:(a,b)\inℂ^2$}
For some convenient help analyzing the problem from the partially helpful point of view of real numbers, I've made a model in desmos, which also serves to bolster confidence that what we seek to prove is indeed the case.
With regards to $a$ and $b$, here is a bit of good news from Wolfram for the case $(a,b)=(i,1)$, which can definitely slightly bolster confidence that the conditions on $a$ and $b$ are probably not too complicated, which is in alignment with my current best guess that any $(a,b)\inℂ^2$ will work.

I'd like to know how to prove that
$$f(x-y)+f\left(\frac{2xy+y^2}{x+y}\right)+f\left(-\frac{2xy+x^2}{x+y}\right)=2f\left(\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}\right)$$ $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2$
and $f: \mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ is $C^\infty$
$\iff$ $f(x) \in$ {$ax^2 + bx^4:(a,b) \in \mathbb{C^2}$}
Assuming the equation holds for all such $(x,y)$, I considered the particular case $y(t)=x(t)=t \in \mathbb{C}$ and arrived at:

$f(0)=0$
$f(t)=f(-t)$ $\forall t \in \mathbb{C}$

but I do not know how to proceed from there

Just a quick note on this question's origin, which also sheds some light on how the question may actually be a bit less 'contrived' so-to-speak than it might at first seem:
This problem was directly inspired from a very similar problem I came across elsewhere on the internet, which is set up as follows.
Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xy+yz+xz=0$.
Find all possible $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ which satisfy $$P(x-y)+P(y-z)+P(z-x)=2P(x+y+z)$$
In attempting to solve that problem, I first considered the special case where $x+y \neq 0$ and then I used the provided condition $xy+yz+xz=0$ to set $$z=\frac{-xy}{x+y}$$ thereby transforming the functional equation into
$$P(x-y)+P(y-\frac{-xy}{x+y})+P(\frac{-xy}{x+y}-x)=2P(x+y+\frac{-xy}{x+y})$$ which can of course be rewritten as
$$P(x-y)+P\left(\frac{2xy+y^2}{x+y}\right)+P\left(-\frac{2xy+x^2}{x+y}\right)=2P\left(\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}\right)$$
which then gave rise to the slightly modified version of the problem that this question is concerned with.

Please do note that I'm concerned with proving that only the zero polynomial as well as all other $f(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ of the form $ax^2+bx^4$ satisfy the functional equation.
My question is not about solving the much easier problem of finding the set of polynomials that satisfy the functional equation, and my question is not about merely proving that
$f(x) \in$ {$ax^2 + bx^4:(a,b) \in \mathbb{C^2}$} $$\implies f(x-y)+f(\frac{2xy+y^2}{x+y})+f(-\frac{2xy+x^2}{x+y})=2f(\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y})∀(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What is addition in $\mathbb{C}P^1$? Maybe it's better to stick with complex numbers and just note that $f$ must be even.

@aschepler Yes, you have a good point, of course. I made and edit, changing $\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$. Does this render the setup issue-free, or do I also need to change $f: \mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ to $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and consider only $(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2:x+y \neq 0$ ? I want to avoid having to consider only the cases where $x+y \neq 0$, for the sake of generality.

Going back to the original nearly equivalent problem, we would like to find all solutions to
$$ xy+yz+zx=0 \implies f(x-y)+f(y-z)+f(z-x) = 2f(x+y+z) $$
but for $C^\infty$ functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, not just polynomials $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.
It will turn out it's enough to assume $f$ is twice differentiable ($C^2$).
Again it's simple to show $f(0)=0$ (using $x=y=z=0$) and $f(-x)=f(x)$ (using $y=z=0$).
Supposing $a=x-y$ and $b=y-z$ and $xy+yz+zx=0$ gives
$$ \begin{align*} y &= x-a \\ z &= x-a-b \\
xy + yz + zx &= 3x^2 - 4ax - 2bx + a^2 + ab = 0 \\
x &= \frac{2a+b \pm \sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}}{3} \\
x+y+z &= 3x - 2a - b = \pm \sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}
\end{align*} $$
So for any $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ (and since $f(y-z) = f(-a-b) = f(a+b)$),
$$ f(a)+f(b)+f(a+b) = 2f\!\left(\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}\right) $$
Since we already know $f(0)=0$, assume $a \neq 0$. Assume $b$ is in the set where $|b| < \frac 12 |a|$, so we know $a^2+ab+b^2 \neq 0$. For convenience, define $c = \sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}$ on this region of $b$ values, using a consistent branch cut for the square root.
Take the partial derivative with respect to $b$, noting $\frac{\partial c}{\partial b} = \frac{a+2b}{2c}$:
$$ f'(b) + f'(a+b) = \frac{a+2b}{c} f'(c) $$
Taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial b}$ again,
$$ f''(b) + f''(a+b) = \frac{(a+2b)^2}{2c^2} f''(c) + \left(\frac 2c - \frac{(a+2b)^2}{2c^3}\right) f'(c) $$
Now set $b=0$. $c=\pm a$ and $f'(-a)=-f'(a)$, so
$$ f''(0) + f''(a) = \frac 12 f''(a) + \frac{3}{2a} f'(a) $$
$$ f''(x) - \frac 3x f'(x) = -2f''(0) $$
This differential equation has solution
$$ f'(x) = Cx^3 + f''(0)\, x $$
Since $f(0)=0$,
$$ f(x) = Ax^4 + Bx^2 $$

I'm making a relatively minor point here, but if I'm allowing $x+y=0$ (as implied by $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2$) then don't we require $f: \mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$?

That said, I do see that the original problem involving the variable $z$ avoids that need by telling us ahead of time that $z$ is not any kind of infinite quantity. Perhaps the problem involving $z$ can be said to be more well-posed since it is less prone to potential issues with quantities that are not well-defined, such as general sums of quantities in complex projective space. I'm really not sure whether or not my version of the problem that omits $z$ and uses $f: \mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ is potentially opening itself up to issues with undefined quantities.

Edit: We are looking for all polynomials $P$ such that $$2P(x)+P(2x)-2P(\sqrt{3}\,  x)=0.$$ This set $E$ is a linear space and $P(x)=x^2$ and $P(x)=x^4$ are in $E.$ If $P\in E$ has degree $r$ then without loss of generality we may assume that
$P(x)=x^r+Q(x)$ with $\deg Q<r.$ Since $ \left(\frac{d}{dr}\right)^rP(ax)=a^rr!$ then $r$ satisfies to the equation
$g(r)=0$ where $$g(r)=2+2^r-2(\sqrt{3})^r.$$
$r=2,4$ are the only solutions of this equation since $g'(r)=0$ has only one solution, necessarily in $(2,4).$ This proves that $\deg P=2$ or $4.$ If $\deg P=2$ then $Q(x)=P(x)-x^2$ is in $E$ and is zero . If $\deg P=4$  then $Q(x)=P(x)-x^4$ is in $E$ and has degree  two or is zero.  Finally
all possible $P$ have the form $P(x)=ax^2+bx^4.$ Nice problem.

If a method eludes us for long enough of proving that only certain polynomials will satisfy the equation then I'll eventually mark this as an accepted answer.

You mean that you need more details?

Can you give more details, especially explains why linear space implies polynomial in the form of $f(x)=x^r$  ? Where does $g$ come from ?

Ok so $\mathbb{C}P_1$ denotes polynomial of $\mathbb{C}$, not convential notation for me, but spend a lot of time to find other properties asssuming to seek solutions in general function :)

@EDX no, it denotes the complex projective line

$CP_1$ means 'projective complex line, meaning $R^2$ plus one point at $\infty$ -homeomorphic to the sphere $S_2.$

@LetacGérard I'm referring to the fact that a crucial part of my question is proving that there do not exist other kinds of solutions than the ones you and I agree are solutions (like perhaps there exist some very strange non-polynomials that happen to solve the functional equation, for example). Proving that other solutions do not exist might very well be the hardest part of the question by far, and what I'm saying is that if days and days and days go by without someone proving other solutions do not exist then I will acknowledge that your answer is probably the best anyone could ever do.

also, take note of the final two sentences of the post :). Again, I might be asking for far too much by requiring proof that other solutions don't exist, and that's why I very well might end up accepting your answer

This isn't a full solution.
As pointed out earlier, by picking something like $y=(1-\sqrt{3})x$ in the original functional equation (this is not the only substitution due to some symmetries therein), after some rescaling we get that
\begin{equation}
2f(x)+f(2x)=2f(\sqrt{3}x) \quad \quad \text{for all } x\in\mathbb C. \quad \quad (*)
\end{equation}
Let us assume that we restrict the search to entire functions $f$. Then the Maclaurin series centered at $0$ has infinite radius of convergence, so we can write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ with convergence everywhere in the complex plane.
Plugging this into our equation, we get that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(2+2^n-2(\sqrt{3})^n)c_nz^n = 0,
\end{equation}
so we must have, for each $n\geq 0$, that $\big(2+2^n-2(\sqrt{3})^n\big)\cdot c_n=0$. However, $2+2^n-2(\sqrt{3})^n=0$ is only satisfied if $n=2$ or if $n=4$. It is easy to see these are the only small solutions and note that the map $n\mapsto \Big(\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)^n-2$ is strictly increasing and it is already positive for $n=5$.
This means that an entire function satisfying $(*)$ must necessarily be of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx^4$ for some complex numbers $a,b$ (this includes the identically $0$ function of course). I will not check this here, but I assume this set of solutions is always consistent with the original functional equation.
The condition of only looking at entire $f$ that satisfy $(*)$ is quite strong though. And there is a big gap between this and assuming something like $f$ just being continuous over the complex plane.
However, it is not difficult to come up with a discontinous example that satisfies $(*)$ but is not strictly of the form above. To be precise, we can look at $f(x)=ax^2+bx^4$, for arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb R$, on the real line and identically $0$ on $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$. It is quite obvious that this will satisfy $(*)$.
'Counterexamples' of this type can also be found if we just think of $f$ acting just on the real line. For instance, for any choice of $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$, we can take $f(x)=ax^2+bx^4$ on $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$ and identically $0$ for the rest of the real line.

I'm a bit concerned by the fact that everyone is agreeing that picking $y=(1-\sqrt{3})x$ yields $2f(x)+f(2x)=2f(\sqrt{3}x)$ after rescaling. To me, it seems that the $f(\frac{2xy+y^2}{x+y})$ term actually becomes $f(-2\sqrt{3}x)$, not $f(2\sqrt{3}x)$. After rescaling, the functional equation then actually becomes $2f(x)+f(-2x)=2f(\sqrt{3}x)$. Would you please double-check that?

it is trivial to check that $f(0)=0$ and that $f(-x)=f(x)$. For example, first pick $y=x$ to get that $f(0)=0$ and then just set $y=0$ to get $f(-x)=f(x)$.

the reason i got to $y=(1-\sqrt{3})x$ is to make two of the arguments in the original functional equation equal. the only choices that give you anything interesting beyond $f(0)=0$ and $f$ being even are $y=(1\pm\sqrt{3})x$ and $y=\tfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}x$ if memory serves. they all boil down to
$2f(x)+f(2x)=2f(\sqrt{3}x)$ in the end.

Oh, that's right. In other words, you're saying that the $f(-2x)$ term that I've gotten (by no mistake) can be replaced with $f(2x)$ for the sake of neatness. And by the way I have no issue with the choice $y=(1-\sqrt{3})x$ and I do see why it's helpful; I was only confused because I was under the impression that one of us must have made a simple calculation mistake and gotten the wrong sign. All is well now; thanks for clearing that up.

Fair. The funny part though is that, at least for the entire $f$ argument, having $f(-2x)$ instead wouldn't change the conclusion.

Also, of course I'm aware of the triviality of deriving that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=f(-x)$; I actually explained in my post the method by which I came to those conclusions myself. I just somehow failed to make the connection that I was allowed to replace $f(-2x)$ with $f(2x)$ :)

Oh I'm silly... I forgot you are the OP :) So yeah, the statement is definitely not true without at least some regularity assumptions on $f$. It is definitely true for $f$ entire (which obviously includes all polys) but not sure if something like just continuity suffices.
